# Is there a way to have a music piece played the moment you enter into a DE?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, music

Is there a way a music piece played the moment you enter into a DE. It would be best if there was a DE-agnostic way so it wouldn't matter which DE I used/floated through. I am looking for something which comes in, puts a random music piece through a collection, when it finishes goes away.

I am guessing this is possible through a bash script or something like that. If there is some way in which this has already been done (some sort of package that does it automatically, with preferences of course) that would be so much more nicer.

Comment: Create a .desktop file (for instance `beep.desktop`) in `.config/autostart`, use your favorite command-line audio player in the Exec= line. [Ref .desktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

Comment: Login sounds used to be all the rage once. Now virtually nobody has it (Linux Mint still uses them, I think.)

Comment: @shirish: What distro do you have? Debian or a derivative of Debian?

Comment: Debian proper - As shared am on unstable/sid, testing and some packages from experimental (pretty much a mixed system.)